# Calling a Resource file Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I call the text file that I have added, ie, i want to read the file and declare the text file as a string. Using Visual Studio 2019, image attached

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcLFX.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve]. Your question is unclear. What is meant by "declare a string as the text file"?

Comment: Share your code, what you have done so far. Where exactly you are stuck. Your question and description is too vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Properties.Resources.ChapterNumberSample` to get the content of the text file as a string.

And you can try to save the lines to a list.

```
string content = Properties.Resources.ChapterNumberSample;
List<string> lines = content.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```